# How can I force a progress bar to update during a long-running operation in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, progress-bar

I am running a test program for VB.NET, and it will simply crunch a million numbers in for loop. I've linked a variable implying the progress of the for loop with the progress bar, but it seems that when I run the program, the progress bar does not update itself. The bar itself has only value 0-100 as input (as stated in the document) and I've tested it without using the for loop, and it works.

I think this has to do with threads, but I am not sure how things work in VB.NET exactly yet. So I want to seek an advice from an expert first.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Yep, threads. The loop should be in another thread. But notice that the UI should ALWAYS be updated in the UI's thread (in .net I **think** it's the main thread). I can't, however, give a complete answer as I only do Mac/iOS development, but I think this is the same everywhere but in a browser.

Comment: Don't do threads in VB 6. It's *possible*, but it's *definitely* not worth it, especially not for something as simple as this.

Comment: Are you doing it in VB6?

Comment: I'm doing this in the Visual Studios 2009.

Comment: I must have missed that version.  Did you mean 2008 or 2010 perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this still applies for .net (or if this is a VB6 question), but [Application.DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) was generally the solution in VB6 days.

Try `Application.DoEvents` inside your loop that updates the progress bar.

Comment: This is correct for VB.NET. In VB 6, you would simply write `DoEvents` (there is no such class `Application`). You should execute this command each iteration of the loop to make sure that your progress bar gets updated.

Comment: Another thing to look at in VB.NET winforms is the backgroundworker under system.componentmodel

Answer (score 1):

long time ago but i think you need the 
DoEvents
statement